# Восстановление БД из резервной копии приводит к проблемам с процедурами (IB XE7)

Tags: база-данных, interbase

Имеется БД, изначально созданная в **IB XE3 Update 4**, которая прекрасно неоднократно восстанавливалась из копий без каких-либо неожиданностей.

После перехода на **IB XE7 Update 1** перестали проходить некоторые тесты хранимых процедур, которые до этого, разумеется, не падали. Вся соль в том, что это происходит только на базе, восстановленной из резервной копии, другими словами есть два сценария:

1. С падением тестов.

   - Берётся БД с XE3-сервера, с помощью XE7 создаётся её копия.
   - База тут же восстанавливается из только что созданной копии.
   - Запускаются тесты - некоторые не проходят.
2. Без падения тестов.

   - Берётся БД с XE3-сервера, в IBExpert создаётся SQL-скрипт на получение её полного дубликата (благо данных в ней мало).
   - Скрипт отрабатывает на сервере XE7 - получаем новую БД.
   - Запускаются тесты - *все* проходят.
   - Выполняем создание резервной копии этой новой базы и тут же восстанавливаем из неё.
   - Запускаются тесты - некоторые не проходят (ровно те же, что и в первом сценарии).
   - Попытки перекомпиляции всех процедур (с отключением пользователей, чтобы кеш метаданных стал актуальным) и обновления индексов ничего не дают. Хотя, один раз удалось каким-то образом восстановить работу тестов, но последовательность действий забылась, т. к. перебиралось всё, что приходило в голову (например, никак не влияющие на логику процедуры правки - добавление лишнего пробела в комментарии, удаление тела и возврат кода обратно...).

Буду рад любым советам по поиску причины такого поведения.

Comment: Выяснилось, что описанная проблема возникает только на последней версии ODS - 16; если в ibconfig уменьшить её до 15 (это версия сервера XE3), то всё работает как надо.

Всё больше склоняюсь в сторону ошибки в самом Interbase, либо в gbak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось обнаружить причину описанного - в блоке for в выборке использовалась та же таблица (`TABLE_1`), что и в блоке do, где она обновлялась:

```
FOR
  SELECT
    REC_ID, /* Первичный ключ. */
    ...
  FROM
    TABLE_1
    ...
  WHERE
    ...
  INTO
    REC_ID,
    ...
DO
BEGIN
  UPDATE TABLE_1
  SET ...
  WHERE REC_ID = :REC_ID;

  ...
END
```

Чтобы избежать побочных эффектов такого использования for-блока, приводивших к проблеме, я предварительно сохранил данные в буферную временную таблицу `TMP_TABLE`:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE
  SELECT
    REC_ID,
    ...
  FROM
    TABLE_1
    ...
  WHERE
    ...;

FOR
  SELECT
    REC_ID,
    ...
  FROM
    TMP_TABLE
  INTO
    REC_ID,
    ...
DO
BEGIN
  UPDATE TABLE_1
  SET ...
  WHERE REC_ID = :REC_ID;

  ...
END
```

В результате такой код корректно работает на обеих версиях ODS (15 и 16).